# Do I need to pay custom charges for moving my personal stuff from Europe to Japan?

Tags: japan, shipping, relocation, customs

I am relocating from Europe (Italy) to Japan, and I will ship most of my personal belongings to my new residence in Japan (a guesthouse in a research institute). Most of the boxes are filled with clothes, and a few electronic devices and some musical instruments. I will ship it with MBE.

Do I need to pay custom charges for moving my personal belongings?
I will declare the approximate value of my stuff, because I would prefer to have an  insurance coverage in case of damage/loss.
Consider that my name appears in both the "sender" and the "recipient" field.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have to pay customs charges for your personal effects that you are sending to Japan. While MBE should provide you with the regulations and documents, this [fact sheet from Atlas International](http://webportal.atlasintl.com/Customs%20Docs/japan.pdf), a US shipper, is an excellent summary of what is required.

> **Customs Regulations**:
>
> Narita Airport Customs officials follow strict enforcement of packing list descriptions/values. Clear descriptions/quantities and value for every item drastically reduces likelihood of having added fees/charges. Proof of overseas residence of more than 6 months; either the visa or Residence Permit must show both the effective date and expiry date.
>
> **Required Documents**:
>
> - Passport Copy – All stamped pages including photo page, entry stamp (must match date on the C5360/2 Form) & visa pages
> - Japanese Visa – Copy; must be valid for 1 year
> - Residence Permit - copy
> - OBL/AWB or Express Release/Waybill
> - Comprehensive Valued Inventory List - in English or Japanese, descriptions such as PBO, HHG, MISC are not allowed; list must contain value, count and description i.e. 9 pants, 25 shirts, 3 coats
> - [Customs Form C5360-2](http://www.customs.go.jp/kaisei/youshiki/form_C/C5360-B.pdf) for non-Japanese or Form 5360 for returning Japanese citizens
>        o Obtained on airplane or at the Customs counter at airport of entry
>        o Must complete two sets and submit to Japanese Customs at the airport
>        o Fill out occupation with name of the company
>        o Customs will stamp both will receive a seal, keep one original to be sent to Destination Agent in Japan (copies or faxed copies not accepted)
> - Delivery address and telephone number

Comment: Thank you for the answer...I think this is what I was looking for. I just don't understand if I have to give this documents to the shipping company or when I will land at the airport. For example I will not get the residence permit before landing in Japan.

Comment: Understood. I'd ask that of [MBE](http://www.mbeglobal.com/product-and-services/shipping/for-everyone/). It may be that MBE also serves as the agent in Japan (it has offices there). The document probably goes with the shipment, and you would want to have a copy with you.